# && operator on strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, operators

I have the following expression :

```
if(a && b === c) {//do something}
```

What would be the meaning of this condition if I consider that a,b, and c are strings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equal to `if (a == true && b === c)`. (note that `==` is lose comparison. Eg. `"foo"` is loosely equal to `true`, however `""` is not loosely equal to true, hence this says "*if `a` is not an empty string, and `b` has the same content, and is the same type as `c`, then do something*")).

**Examples**:

```
var a = 'foo';
var b = 'bar';
var c = 'bar';
```

Will be `true` because `a` is not falsy (a non empty string is truthy), and `b` is the same type and has the same content as `c`.

```
var a = '';
var b = 'bar';
var c = 'bar';
```

Will be `false` because `a` is falsy (an empty string is falsy).

```
var a = 'foo';
var b = 'rab';
var c = 'bar';
```

Will be `false` because `b` does not have the same content as `c`.

```
var a = 'foo';
var b = true;
var c = 1;
```

Will be `false` because `b` is not the same type as `c` (`boolean` vs `number` - with `==` this would be `true`, as `true == 1`).

Answer (score 1):

This means:

`a is truthy 
 AND 
 b exactly equal to c (including type)`

Here `a is truthy` means it is NOT ('undefined' or "" or 'null' or 0 or 'NaN' or 'FALSE')

Comment: That's a very incomplete definition of "truthy".

Comment: The other possible falsey values don't correspond to the proposed string data type of `a` (NaN, 0, false)

Comment: Well, neither do `undefined` and `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression expands to this:

```
if (a) {
  if (b === c) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

It first checks that `a` is some truthy value. It then checks that `b` and `c` are of the same value *and* the same type. [Read up on truthy and falsey values in JavaScript](http://zero.milosz.ca/).

Answer (score 1):

if  a have some value (not null and "") and b's value (string, case sensitive) is equal to c's value then your code